# Highcharts maxWidth or maxHeight of map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, highcharts

I'm trying to set the `maxWidth` of my world map with `highcharts` but it doesn't change the size.

I've tried these:

```
responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 500
            },
...
```

As suggested [here](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/responsive.rules.condition.maxWidth) and [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/responsive/axis/).

```
chart: {
    maxWidth: 1024
},
```

As suggested [here](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.width), [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/width/).

I'm using the code from [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-zs69rw?file=index.tsx).

> Update 10 Feb 2020:

Following the suggestion below, I use this code which can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-99q5cw?file=index.tsx):

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts/highmaps';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';

import mapDataWorld from '@highcharts/map-collection/custom/world.geo.json';

var data: [string, number][] = [
    // data can be found in the link
];


const options: Highcharts.Options = {
    chart: {
      height: 400
    },

    series: [{
        type: 'map',
        mapData: mapDataWorld,
        data: data,
    }],

    responsive: {
      rules: [{
        chartOptions: {
          chart: {
            height: 800
          },
          legend: {
              margin: 0
          },
          title: {
            margin: 0
          },
        },
        condition: {
          maxWidth: 1024
        }
      }]
    }
}

const App = (props: HighchartsReact.Props) =>  <div style={{
  maxWidth: '1024px',
}}>
    <HighchartsReact
        options={options}
        highcharts = { Highcharts }
        constructorType={'mapChart'}
                {...props}
    />
</div>

ReactDom.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Then open the result in a new window.
[image]
You'll see the map is pushed below the top of the screen in mobile view in Google Chrome. This still happens with `margin: 0`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
responsive: {
    rules: [{
        condition: {
            maxWidth: 500
        },
...
```

Above option is a condition for which the next defined chart option will be applied, in case of shared demo is:

```
chartOptions: {
    xAxis: {
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.value.charAt(0);
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        labels: {
            align: 'left',
            x: 0,
            y: -2
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        }
    }
}
```

Highcharts doesn't offer a chart.maxWidth feature, only the chart.width feature as you shared from the API to set the fixed value for chart width.

You can set the max-width for the div where Highcharts map is rendering, but remember about importing CSS.

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-5upg3v?file=index.tsx

Or without CSS as inline-style - demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-uy5xkd?file=index.tsx

Comment: Thank you Sebastian, let me try it and get back to you.

Comment: Sure, we can continue this thread here or in case of a new issue start a new topic.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of them scales up the actual map (the `svg`), only the div (white space) contains it.

Comment: Maybe using the responsive rules to change chart height while div width has changed could be a good solution, like here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-nyzu6y?file=index.tsx

Comment: It does change the size (height) of the svg map but in mobile views, there's a huge gap between the top and the actual map. It loses its responsiveness.

Comment: Without setting the responsive rules or by setting RWD on the div by using CSS the chart will keep the 400 px height. You will need to set responsivity if you want to avoid those gaps between the top and map. You can also get some space by setting the legend.margin and title.margin to 0. Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-99q5cw?file=index.tsx

Comment: Thank you @Sebastian for your patience. It still doesn't work for me. Using the example in the link, can you try to set the height to `800px` and the `maxWidth: 1024px`, open as a new window with Chrome and switch to mobile view like iPhone SE or Galaxy S5, you'll see what I meant.

Comment: The height of the map container is set, so in smaller screen sizes, the actual map is pushed down. Maybe I'm missing something. I've tried setting CSS rules for the `highcharts-container` or 'highcharts-series` or `highcharts-series-group`, etc but none of them works.

Comment: Could you send me your demo with the options which you had described in the above comment? I checked my last demo in the Chrome in the mobile view and looks fine.

Comment: This one: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-99q5cw?file=index.tsx also I'll update my question so you can see the code and the screenshot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207585/discussion-between-sebastian-wedzel-and-viet).